# Non-supersymmetric CFT in $d=4, 5, 6$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, conformal-field-theory, big-list

There's no known interacting CFT in $d>6$, see [Interacting CFT in $d>6$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/563741/)

Also we know a lot CFT in $d=2$ (minimal models for example) and in $d=3$ (WF fixed points in $4-\epsilon$ approach to different models in SFT).

**But what we know about non-SUSY CFT in $4≤d≤6$? Which examples we can present?**

For example, I know about:

- The Banks-Zaks IR fixed point -- theories in the conformal window for gauge theories with matter
- The Litim-Sannino UV fixed point:

[image]

But unfortunately I didn't know such examples in $d≥4$ and another examples in $d=4$.

I will be very appreciate for any suggestions!

Comment: I think your question is a very nice and difficult to answer one. [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.00023) provides an example to your question in 5d.

Comment: Also of interest might be these two bootstrap papers, [1705.05401](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.05401) and  [1902.05969](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.05969), studying the space of 4d CFTs (the second one explicitly studying non-SUSY ones). There is also [some evidence](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.07307) for non-unitary CFTs in 5d

Comment: @4xion I think non-unitary CFTs most likely exist in higher dimensions -- we are pretty comfortable with the idea of Wilson-Fisher fixed points being parametrized by spacetime dimension $d$, and I think it is reasonable to expect their OPE data can be analytically continued to $d=5$ and beyond, where it yields a non-unitary CFT.